# RegEx that excludes characters doesn't begin matching until 2nd character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will include all ascii but exclude certain characters such as "+" or "%" - I'm currently using this:

```
^[\x00-\x7F][^%=+]+$
```

But I noticed (using various RegEx validators) that this pattern only begins matching with 2 characters. It won't match "a" but it will match "ab." If I remove the "[^]" section, (^[\x00-\x7F]+$) then the pattern matches one character. I've searched for other options, but so far come up with nothing. I'd like the pattern to begin matching on 1 character but also exclude characters. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:(?![%=+])[\x00-\x7F])+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nP6nL3/1).**

---

This will loop through, make sure that the "bad" characters aren't there with a negative lookahead, then match the "good" characters, then repeat.

Comment: I think you were first (by a scratch) but both answers were great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative lookahead here to exclude certain characters:

```
^((?![%=+])[\x00-\x7F])+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ3vV5/2)

`(?![%=+])` is a **negative lookahead** that will assert that matched character is not one of the `[%=+]`.

Comment: Your answer was just as good as the one I marked, but his was about 1 minute ahead. Great answer, though! Thank you!

Comment: Actually my answer was faster. My timestamp: `16:06:59` and his: `16:07:13` i.e. 14 seconds late than me :)

Comment: Yea, I saw yours popup as I was copy/pasting the demo link :P

Answer (score 0):

You could simply exclude those chars from the `\x00-\x7f` range (using the hex value of each char).

```
+----------------+
|Char|Dec|Oct|Hex|
+----------------+
| %  |37 |45 |25 |
+----------------+
| +  |43 |53 |2B |
+----------------+
| =  |61 |75 |3D |
+----------------+
```

**Regex:**

```
^[\x00-\x24\x26-\x2A\x2C-\x3C\x3E-\x7F]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yG5nW2/1)

Engine-wise this is more efficient than attempting an assertion for each character.